# Login permission on Availability group database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, availability-groups, logins

We have an availability group database. Just wanted to check on the below statement  whether it needs to be run on all replica (By failing over and making it primary)or it can be run on the primary and the permission will be replicated to the replicas.

```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE, VIEW DEFINITION ON [DB_Lock] TO sqlogin
```

`SQLOGIN` is a sql login and has been mapped to the  availability group database user.

`DB_Lock` is a table on the Availability group database. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If the database is in high availability group, then No, you do not need to failover, once you do it on the primary replica, it will be picked up and replicated to to other secondary replicas. 
Of course, we assume the sql login exists already on all replicas.

Comment: *and* that it has the same SID on all replicas.

Comment: same SID on all replicas as it is in  production we often fail over during upgrades